# User Defined Rules in a Web Application

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, rules

I'm required to implement a notification system integrated to a web application (JavaScript + PHP). Notifications should be fired based on user-defined rules. I don't have experience with rules engines and building rules. Therefore, I don't know what I'm doing or if what the following could be implemented by better solution.

I'm trying to figure out how to store and process the following hypothetical scenario. Let's say that the web app is a shopping online service for a store that has 3 lines of products, line A, line B and line C. Each line has different characteristics. User#1 selects an object from line A, then specifies some characteristics such as size and colors. User#2 selects an object from line B, the only characteristic for this kind is material, he selects wood. Then both users ask system to notify them whenever these objects with these characteristics become available.

From what I've read so far, this could be done through [user-defined rules]. If so, then

- What's the best technology to handle it? I'm willing to learn but I need a direction to help me start.
- Can I use openRules or similar for this?
- How to sent user defined data to a web service? given that they change based on the line.

Comment: I'm familiar with php, cron jobs, sql and postgresql. The only thing I'm new at is implementing and firing rules. also, how to deal with different variables from different users

Comment: rules can be urls that return no results or one+ results. typically, urls translate to sql, but it's probably simplest to use urls so you can run everything through your normal security. in short, you can basically "bookmark" the url where you see the empty list, and try again later to see if it's not empty. then you just need to store a url and an email address, occasionally ping the urls, and if cool, email the address and delete the row.

Comment: Thanks dandavis! I'd like to know more about this approach. Can you provide me with some resources?

Comment: no, it's something i just made up to solve your particular problem if  i were to try. money back guarantee included that it works ;) you can use cron to run curl to run php snips that do the checking and emailing...

Comment: lol well, thanks for your hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a database, or anything similar, you can make a table where you would save the rules for each user. You can than later load them with a php class as soon as the user logs in, and check against them before doing anything that was optional.

You can also make a table and set flags, once an item becomes available loop trough the table and notify every user waiting. You would need to store, item id and customer id, in the table and delete them once they have been notify.

Comment: Many thanks Daniel! This is really helpful for me!

Comment: Im glad we can help if you have any more questions, just leave a comment here.